# How to convert file of strings separated by a new line to array

Tags: bash, shell, variable, array

I have a file with data like this:

```
UserName
UserName
UserName
```

Each piece of data is separated by a new line.

I need that data to be converted to an array of strings and stored in a variable.

How do I achieve this with just bash or shell execution?

Comment: Can there be multiple strings per line (separated by space or even tab or comma)? If yes, should they be stored as one or as multiple values?

Comment: only one string per line, theyre each stored as a single value. each string is only seperated by a new line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `mapfile`:

```
$ mapfile -t array < yourfile

$ declare -p array # print array content
  declare -a array=([0]="UserName" [1]="UserName" [2]="UserName")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ set -f             # disable globbing
$ arr=($(<file.csv))
$ set +f             # enable globbing
$ declare -p arr     # print array content
declare -a arr=([0]="UserName" [1]="UserName" [2]="UserName")
```

- `arr=(…)` create array
- `$(<file.csv)` read file `file.csv` (like `$(cat file.csv)`)

Before the file is read, globbing should be disabled to prevent the expansion of user names with characters like `*` or `?` or special patterns (pathname expansion).

The elements are split at newline, space or tab characters (assuming `$IFS` has not been modified) and trimmed.

Answer (score 2):

```
i=0
while IFS= read -r line
do
  var[i++]="$line"
done < filename
```

Here var array variable stores all names. And can be accessed by

```
printf '%s\n' "${var[0]}"
printf '%s\n' "${var[1]}"
...
...
```